# When using multiple classes with the same name, should you fully qualify all uses, or just the "rare" ones?

Tags: java, class, import, namespaces

In Java, when using multiple classes that have the same name in one class, should you always fully qualify all uses of those classes? For example:

```
org.foo.ClassA;
gov.bar.ClassA;
```

In the more specific case that one of those classes is very common in your codebase, is it acceptable to only fully qualify the unusual one? If, for example, I worked for gov.bar, but was add code from a library from org.foo?

Comment: Your governing principle should be clarity.  Do what makes it easiest for other programmers looking at your code to understand it.

Comment: `ClassA` There is a fine line between abstraction and obfuscation, and I think that calling classes by letters crosses that line.  Perhaps if you named some actual classes along with their packages, others would argue that the classes should *not* have the same name.

Comment: Can you refactor the names so they get different?

Comment: Using two existing libraries, so not really. I know it's not ideal, but the question is really about what the best option is when you have two classes with the same name [and can't change them].

Comment: @AndrewThompson I can't help but assume that `ClassA` is merely an example and not actually the class involved, unless the dev team at bar.gov is suddenly active again.

Comment: @corsiKa  *"can't help but assume that `ClassA` is merely an example"* Well.. duh.  That is why I added *"..if you named some **actual** classes.."*  If I'd thought those were actual class names my advice would've been more along the lines *"First thing, sack whoever designed that code/named those classes.."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the most important question is "what do the other people who are working on the codebase expect?". Working against a well-known coding standard is the best approach.

If you don't know who will have to maintain code in the codebase, fully qualifying both is probably the clearest approach.

Comment: I think this overriding principle of clarity and matching the group's coding standards is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, avoid this when you can. It's a common source of frustration among developers. (`java.awt.List` and `java.util.List` anyone?)

In cases where you can't avoid it, you're best off fully qualifying both of them in class files that use them both. Chances are, this is a rare occasion that both will be in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use generics to effectively rename the classes.  The below compiled for me.  It works best if the classes with the same name are not generic.

```
class TestIt < UtilList extends java . util . List , AWTList extends java . awt . List >
{
    public void run ( UtilList utilList , AWTList awtList )
    {
    }
}
```